# Echoing prior to pinging a host with FOR loop in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I would like to know how I would write the code with my FOR loop prior to pinging the host, write to the screen “Trying to ping B217-##”

this is my FOR loop:

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%n%) DO (if %%a LSS 10 (ping -n 2 %r%-0%%a ) 
    if %%a GTR 10 (ping -n 2 %r%-%%a) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply use `echo` command at the point you need it

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%n%) DO (
   if %%a LSS 10 (
     echo Trying to ping -n 2 %r%-0%%a 
     ping -n 2 %r%-0%%a 
   ) else ( 
     echo Trying to ping -n 2 %r%-%%a
     ping -n 2 %r%-%%a
   ) 
)
```

note that I have also simplified and corrected a bit your `IF`